# how to download World MODIS image from ESRI ImageServer?

Tags: modis, download

I need to download the following dataset that is available online in ESRI website: https://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World/MODIS/ImageServer. I can view the map in arcmap as instructed but I need to download the original raster so that I can further process. This layer has 12 files of 12 different months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layer provided by ESRI is designed for "view-only" purpose. I don't think you can download the actual data using it. USGS is probably the way to go if you want to get the actual MODIS data.